# Gnuplot log plot y-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have have a .txt file with some values as a function of iteration count. And I am trying to log plot it. I have managed to do this with the following code `plot 'solchange.txt' using 1:(log($2)) with lines`

The x axis is perfect and the shape is perfect, but my y axis is weird. I want it to be say 10^-2 and 10^-3 and so on how can this be done?[image]

What does -16 even mean? My value stops at 10^-7

solchange.txt

```
1  0.20870164249629861  
   2   3.0540936828943599E-002
   3   2.1622388854567132E-002
   4   1.7070994407582529E-002
   5   1.4155375579083168E-002
   6   1.2069370098131457E-002
   7   1.0482626276465484E-002
   8   9.2258609277672127E-003
   9   8.2010529631910967E-003
  10   7.3466561929682317E-003
  11   6.6216556909214075E-003
  12   5.9973025525987822E-003
  13   5.4526144028317000E-003
  14   4.9718850942694140E-003
  15   4.5432279303643033E-003
  16   4.1576291151408026E-003
  17   3.8082604242292567E-003
  18   3.4899438987894341E-003
  19   3.1987266873885617E-003
  20   2.9315478643644408E-003
  21   2.6859845807917955E-003
  22   2.4600648490906499E-003
  23   2.2521338021345080E-003
  24   2.0607609516045851E-003
  25   1.8846776035151558E-003
  26   1.7227356558349102E-003
  27   1.5738810584753488E-003
  28   1.4371370123238449E-003
  29   1.3115934299711522E-003
  30   1.1964002798033561E-003
  31   1.0907632352794312E-003
  32   9.9394061400687704E-004
  33   9.0524097544450455E-004
  34   8.2402100116123200E-004
  35   7.4968344624489966E-004
  36   6.8167505353953529E-004
  37   6.1948438470904935E-004
  38   5.6263955830880997E-004
  39   5.1070590513836635E-004
  40   4.6328356186664012E-004
  41   4.2000502958110253E-004
  42   3.8053272709547871E-004
  43   3.4455657088288370E-004
  44   3.1179161480603731E-004
  45   2.8197578322736866E-004
  46   2.5486773011298286E-004
  47   2.3024485386036100E-004
  48   2.0790149243582034E-004
  49   1.8764731601648640E-004
  50   1.6930592515617369E-004
  51   1.5271365239171797E-004
  52   1.3771855529436799E-004
  53   1.2417958039480804E-004
  54   1.1196587112561468E-004
  55   1.0095618950593192E-004
  56   9.1038420860557225E-005
  57   8.2109133101636398E-005
  58   7.4073166362883126E-005
  59   6.6843234255131376E-005
  60   6.0339523889261799E-005
  61   5.4489287395236962E-005
  62   4.9226422450250433E-005
  63   4.4491043040285547E-005
  64   4.0229044229763214E-005
  65   3.6391666180476002E-005
  66   3.2935063208632334E-005
  67   2.9819883516037614E-005
  68   2.7010864597994382E-005
  69   2.4476448415957416E-005
  70   2.2188419389643915E-005
  71   2.0121567231942521E-005
  72   1.8253375701611941E-005
  73   1.6563737530794070E-005
  74   1.5034695117064744E-005
  75   1.3650206056065907E-005
  76   1.2395932219765905E-005
  77   1.1259050839256858E-005
  78   1.0228085910393529E-005
  79   9.2927581834059692E-006
  80   8.4438520049430650E-006
  81   7.6730973352498108E-006
  82   6.9730653504927742E-006
  83   6.3370761471119759E-006
  84   5.7591171842940984E-006
  85   5.2337712233988323E-006
  86   4.7561526453150822E-006
  87   4.3218511441380815E-006
  88   3.9268819066553586E-006
  89   3.5676414890935086E-006
  90   3.2408686962536598E-006
  91   2.9436098531714777E-006
  92   2.6731879338693330E-006
  93   2.4271750801384794E-006
  94   2.2033681015580162E-006
  95   1.9997666008135691E-006
  96   1.8145534130165238E-006
  97   1.6460770886038423E-006
  98   1.4928361827763054E-006
  99   1.3534651455843205E-006
 100   1.2267216317977253E-006
 101   1.1114750729309016E-006
 102   1.0066963732594143E-006
 103   9.1144860808961906E-007
 104   8.2487861805891419E-007
 105   7.4620940497668528E-007
 106   6.7473324671810456E-007
 107   6.0980545750098300E-007
 108   5.5083872884395882E-007
 109   4.9729799312444450E-007
 110   4.4869575892107771E-007
 111   4.0458787177585429E-007
 112   3.6456965996078949E-007
 113   3.2827242845258689E-007
 114   2.9536026832557155E-007
 115   2.6552715221570336E-007
 116   2.3849428917172011E-007
 117   2.1400771520012352E-007
 118   1.9183609798172768E-007
 119   1.7176873612963911E-007
 120   1.5361373552607444E-007
 121   1.3719634701231387E-007
 122   1.2235745044898369E-007
 123   1.0895217281928909E-007
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log(x) is natural log. You need to use log10(x) if you want base 10.

Another, probably better way would be to use a logarithmic y axis like so:

```
set format y '%g' 
set logscale y
plot 'solchange.txt' using 1:2 with lines
```

Use `help set format` to figure out how to change the y-axis tics.

Comment: Found it :) To get 10^-1 and so on you need to add "set format y "10^{%L}""